# SimpleAuth not returning Instagram response

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, simple-authentication

I have been trying to create an iOS app with SimpleAuth to authenticate Instagram.

In my AppDelegate.swift I have:

```
SimpleAuth.configuration()["instagram"] = ["client_id": "MY-CLIENT-ID", SimpleAuthRedirectURIKey: "MY-REDIRECT-URL"]
```

(Obviously inserting the client ID and redirect URI where needed)

And in my ViewController.swift I have:

```
    @IBAction func instagramAuthenticate(sender: AnyObject) {

    SimpleAuth.authorize("instagram", options: ["scope" : ["likes"]], completion: {
        (responseObject : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

        println("\(responseObject)")
    })
}
```

For some reason when the user authorizes my app, the responseObject appears to return 'nil'. Possible meaning something went wrong.

I am relatively new to Swift/iOS and am not sure what I have done incorrectly. Thanks

Comment: Check if error isn't nil and maybe error.description provides enough information to get a hint about what's going wrong

Comment: @HorseT Thanks so much for that. I wrote a previous comment with the error which was something todo with the UIWebView not being able to process the URL properly, or something strange like that. Turned out it was todo with the Redirect URI, which I then changed and everything worked perfectly! Thanks

Comment: Ahh, too late. Was it the missed second "/"? Seemed a little bit like that. Coding on ;)

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure it was actually. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out my redirect URI was the reason it was returning nil. I changed it and everything worked perfectly! Thanks to HorseT in the comments above.

**Edit: More in-depth answer below**

All the following information can be found [here](https://github.com/calebd/SimpleAuth).

Firstly, you must configure Instagram in your `AppDelegate.swift`

```
//Instagram Confifuration
    SimpleAuth.configuration()["instagram"] = ["client_id": "YOUR-CLIENT-ID", SimpleAuthRedirectURIKey: "myApp://Auth/instagram"]
```

Make sure the `SimpleAuthRedirectURIKey` is equal to that in your app settings on the [instagram developers page](https://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/).

[image]

Next you need to authorize the user.

```
SimpleAuth.authorize("instagram", options: ["scope" : ["basic", "comments", "likes", "relationships"]], completion: {
(responseObject : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
if (responseObject != nil) {
    var instagramResponse = responseObject as! NSDictionary
    var accessToken : String = instagramResponse["credentials"]!["token"] as! String
    println(accessToken)
} else {
    println(error.localizedDescription)
}
}
```

This simply gets the response and prints the accessToken.

From here on you can access [endpoints](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) to retrieve further data.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Matt, im having problem using Instagram API inside my app, Can you please tell me how do i redirect the user back to the app after he logged in and pressed the "Authorize" button? Thanks!

Comment: Hey matt! I actually succeed doing this last night lol. The new instructions from Apple guidelines dosent let you go out of the app to safari, you must you webview. So i guess the URI could be anything lol. am i right? It dosent matter which address im putting?

Comment: Haha thats good! Yes, although the webview is still within the app I believe that the redirect URI still should still match the one on the instagram site. @roimulia

Comment: Can i pick any adress? I mean if i have huge traffic does it matter?

Comment: Yep! "myApp://Auth/instagram" was the simplest I could think of but it can really be anything. @roimulia

Comment: Dosent it matter which url im responding? + in theory if i have million users, there is a way of handling it ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't think I can help you with that as I am not too sure @roimulia